# can I split a browser screen (same tab)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, opera, split-window

say I am viewing a large code chunk/article and when I read on, I want to keep one part as a reference. How can I do that? Sometimes duplicate page is not an option because access to the page may only be granted once (during a test for example).

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/side-view/

This seems to be exactly what you are looking for, except that you have to manually drag resize the sidebar to fill a screen equally.

Comment: Almost there! But I used google doc to test and I think technically it opens the same tab twice. What I really need is something like microsoft doc split screen so you only open the tab once...

Comment: There's some more options on Mozilla addons https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tile-tabs-we/ also a bad Google Chrome attempt https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-scissors/cdochbecpfdpjobpgnacnbepkgcfhoek its hard to create such an advanced extension, even in Firefox. You probably won't be able to scroll with both tabs simultaneously etc. it will all be a pretty big hack prone to breaking.

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sideside/bobidkladfnoamglfgpnllbkhjlhjlfb

This extension does this perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).